# How to assign Page-wise privileges programmatically in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-membership, privileges, user-roles

I have an asp.net application which has web.config file in every folder of the application. Every folder has many aspx pages in it.I need to assign/deny privileges through coding for every individual pages of folders.The privileges is role based privileges.so some roles will have privileges to only some pages in each folder.
Please help me how to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, control permissions by folder is the easiest.

But, try this:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871